# Mobile Select Won't Focus

Tags: javascript, html

on mobile, everytime a field gets filled, the enter key is pressed. This in turn focuses the next element. Unfortunately it works for all except a select. It'll completely skip the select control and go to input.

Example found here https://jsfiddle.net/dv5zbtn6/3/

```html
<form method="POST" class="rsvp-form js-form" id="rsvp-form" action="php/rsvp.php">
   <div class="d-md-flex justify-content-between">
      <div class="rsvp-form__left">
         <div class="rsvp-form-field">
            <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name" required>
         </div>
         <div class="rsvp-form-field">
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your E-mail" class="js-email" required />
         </div>
         <div class="rsvp-form-field">
            <input type="text" name="guests" placeholder="Will you be bringing a plus one?" required>
         </div>
         <div class="rsvp-form-field">
            <select name="attending" required tabindex="1">
               <option value="" disabled selected>When we say 'I do', will we be seeing you?</option>
               <option value="Yes, wouldn't miss it for the world!"></option>
               <option value="No, will celebrate from afar!"></option>
               <option value="ceremony">Ceremony</option>
               <option value="party">Dinner & Party</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="rsvp-form__right">
         <div class="rsvp-form-field h-100">
            <textarea rows="4" placeholder="Your Message" class="h-100" name="message"></textarea>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="rsvp-form-submit js-submit">
   <span>Send</span>
   </button>
</form>
```

I tried setting tabindex but that unfortunately didn't work. Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50817217/when-i-select-next-from-my-android-device-while-filling-a-form-it-skips-any-dr). This behaviour is not a bug per se. It's just that the Next/Enter button on a mobile, is not the same as a Tab button on a keyboard. The Enter button on a mobile specifically searches for the next typeable input field, rather than the next focusable one.